# iOS: Disable/delete/hide previous ViewController from Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, account

In my login logic I have a "AuthenticationViewController" (here the application checks if the user is already logged in). I also use storyboard and all views are based on push segues. And so it looks:

```
                                    ------ AccountViewController
                                   |
-->  AuthenticationViewController  +
                                   |
                                    ------ LoginViewController
```

Now when I use the UITabbarController and press twice on the tabbar icon "account", the application pops back to the AuthenticationViewController and then to the accountView or to the loginView. I know it's a "blemish" but how can I achieve that when I press twice at the account-icon, the AuthenticationViewController does not get shown? Or do I have a wrong logic?

**EDIT**

This is how my push-function gets initialized programmatically in the authenticationViewController:

```
// Delegate to AccountViewController if Data (Username, Password) is correct

if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    AccountViewController *AVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AccountView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:AVC animated:NO];
    // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"authAccountSegue" sender:self];
}
else {
    LoginViewController *LVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:LVC animated:NO];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do exactly the same thing in one of my apps, and this doesn't happen. Does it also happen on the device?

Comment: hi 8vius :) yes, of course.. I do know why this happens: the tabbar brings the user back to the first view, if he pressed it twice. And in my case, the authenticationViewController is the first view... Can you please send me a picture of your storyboard? Maybe it's a small mistake..

Comment: Ok, I think I know what the problem is, do you segue to one of the views or to the tab bar controller?

Comment: the only segue that exists is between the tabbar contoller and the authenticationViewController. the other connections are all programmatically.

Comment: could you show us some related code?

Comment: Ok Carina, added both. Maybe you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved this problem on my own: SUBVIEWS are the key :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there's 2 things I see here, not sure if they'll help towards fixing your problem exactly though. The first is that you could just set up the segues for both actions and there wouldn't be much difference. The other is that looking at your storyboard structure the Login and Account controllers seem to be more suited to be a modal view instead of pushing it onto the stack.

Comment: It does not make a difference if I connect the views with segues. My first project was based on modal view function but I must retain my tabbar :S difficult, huh?

Comment: Do you actually need the tab bar in these views? Because it seems like they contain isolated actions, where's the benefit from having the tab bar there? Seems a somewhat weird navigation pattern.

Comment: to retain the tabbar you can do a push segue or do it with some code. I thought without segues it could solve my problem...

Comment: It makes sense that if you retain the tab bar in these views the problem happens, because it's still there in the background. I think your only way is to to a modal segue

Comment: After viewing your code and storyboard I can see my project is quite different. I have one initial controller that later pushes a tab bar controller, so I don't really have this issue.